# Possible reasons for EntityNotFoundException

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Under what circumstances could a [`get()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#get(com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key)) in Google AppEngine throw an [`EntityNotFoundException`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/EntityNotFoundException)?

Does it truly **only** happen if the requested key does not exist in the datastore at the time of the request, or could it also happen because of some other issue during the call, like for example a time-out?

In other words, if I start a new transaction and a `get()` in that transaction throws an `EntityNotFoundException`, can I be **100%** certain that a `put()` in that same transaction will **never** overwrite some already existing entry, that the `get()` somehow missed?

To add some code:

```
private Entity getOrCreate(Key key, String initialData) {
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Transaction txn = datastore.beginTransaction();
    try {
        Entity result;
        try {
            // Try to read existing entity
            result = datastore.get(key);
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
            // If entity is not found, create and put a new one
            result = new Entity(key);
            result.setProperty("data", initialData);
            datastore.put(result); // Could this EVER overwrite an existing entity?
        }
        txn.commit();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (txn.isActive()) txn.rollback();
    }
}
```

Could this code **ever** overwrite an existing entity by accident due to some mechanism that leads to the EntityNotFoundException **other** than this entity truly not existing?

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing a transaction, your whole entity group will be frozen by the transaction until you commit it.  So in your case, if the entity group is locked, there is no real chance of someone "pushing" his own entity between your get and put.

The only issue I could personally see with the "entityNotFound" has to do with eventual consistency. For instance if the instance is created but not yet fully consistent, certain get() queries could return "EntityNotFound".  I would use a strongly consistent query (like get_by_id) to make sure your datastore is consistent.

the ONLY time you should receive an "EntityNotFound" error is from an entity that doesn't get caught.  In that case, it's either the entity doesn't exist, or the consistency isn't strong yet.  Using a strongly consistent query (ancestor query or get_by_id) will fix that.

Looking at [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency) might help you restructure your models :)

Comment: @MarkusA. Makes WAY more sense now :).  Check my edited answer, might help you ^^

Comment: :) Yep! Thanks! :) I deleted my comments and instead edited my question a little. And it's exactly that "eventual consistency" case that is one example that I'm worried about. Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure what you mean by "get_by_id". Do you mean an actual "get()" for a specific key rather than a query?

Comment: But basically you are saying that no other error mechanism (a read timeout or something) can cause the error?

Comment: not that I know of. Read timeouts will usually trigger a "deadline exceeded". If you get a "entityNotFound" you can safely assume that there is a problem with your entity (AFAIK again :P).  For the get_by_id, it was python and not java.  So your only choice would be ancestor queries.  I added a link to my answer :)

Comment: Gotcha... I'll leave the question open for a bit longer to see if someone from the AppEngine team has a different view on this issue, but if no other info comes up, you get the √. :)